# Restaurar rotas após o comando route -F?

Tags: cmd, configuração, route

Olá, boa noite/madrugada!

Estou pesquisando aqui sobre o comando route -f, que para mim era desconhecido. 
Hoje a tarde meu irmão curioso estava mexendo na cmd, tentando entender os comandos "route", mas ele acabou desconfigurando algo e ficamos sem internet.

Estou na 3g, socorro! Ele me afirmou que a internet só caiu após o comando route -f e partido dessa informação comecei a pesquisar, só que não estou encontrando nada que realmente resolva o nosso problema. Sou bem leiga em rede.

Usamos internet via-rádio, no caso, tem a antena no telhado e aqui dentro de casa um "receptor", ou modem, não tenho certeza.  (Carrier POE Adapter - Ubiquiti)

Usei ipconfig /release - /renew e agora voltou a aparecer  o 10.1.1.1 quando utilizo ipconfig para ver o gateway, também consigo pingar para o modem/receptor, no caso, 10.1.1.1, mas não consigo abre mais a interface. Eu não tenho acesso a interface, digo, adm e senha, mas sei que sempre abria a tela de login, agora nem isso.

Ah sim, e esse comando que ele executou acabou por danificar a internet não apenas aqui no "PC", mas para todos os computadores aqui de casa. Pode modem/receptor  ter sido desconfigurado com o comando pela cmd?

Alguma luz? Muito obrigada!